# Trying to display a series of random numbers in a textbox then write them to file and display in a listbox

Tags: file, text

I am generating random numbers (one at a time shown) and I wish to show all of the numbers so generated in a textbox. Also the series is written to a text file which (on clicking display) I can show in a listbox.

I can't get the textbox to show each number generated.
When I try to display the text file I get two of each number.

```
Dim filename As String = "nums.dat"
Dim index As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Btnstart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnstart.Click
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Lblrandomnum.Text = rnd.Next(0, 101)
    For Each I In Lblrandomnum.Text
        txtstore.Text = Lblrandomnum.Text
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Append)
        WriteLine(1, Lblrandomnum.Text)
        FileClose()
        Next I
End Sub

Private Sub Btndisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btndisplay.Click
    Dim datatodisplay As String
    FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)
    lstdisplay.Items.Clear()
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        datatodisplay = LineInput(1)
        lstdisplay.Items.Add(datatodisplay)
    Loop
    FileClose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code in your question [Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/)?